# Is there are way to make the simple sub division look less ugly?

Tags: mesh, texturing, texture-baking, subdivision-surface, pbr

For my model i had to give it the simple subdiv with adaptive subdiv for the pbr textures to work properly. is there any way to make the model look smoother without affecting the pbr texture quality, or is this how it has to be, can it be fixed with baking normals?

[image]

Comment: No, you know that very well.

Comment: If you've subdivided without smoothing it will just add topology, it won't round the shape